# How to generate PKCE code verifier and challenge

Tags: c, oauth

I'm writing a small C library for my projects to do oauth authentication and I am not sure how to generate the code verifier and challenge and what libraries I should use. I would like to use as few dependencies as possible.

I've seen it done in this google example but I'm not sure how to implement it in C.
https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthUniversalApp/OAuthUniversalApp/MainPage.xaml.cs

```
...
string state = randomDataBase64url(32);
string code_verifier = randomDataBase64url(32);
string code_challenge = base64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256(code_verifier));
const string code_challenge_method = "S256";
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. I coded my own base64 encoding, this wikipedia article was very useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64. Then I also coded a random (url safe) string generation function. And last but not least grabbed this small standalone sha256 library https://github.com/amosnier/sha-2

In the end my code looks something like this.

```
char* code_verifier = base64_url_random(32);
uint8_t hash[32];
char hash_string[65];
calc_sha_256(hash, code_verifier, strlen(code_verifier));
hash_to_string(hash_string, hash);
char* code_challenge = base64_url_encode(hash_string);
```